# Filter the values using angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angularjs-ng-click

I have a web application where I have many forms which i have created using bootstrap modal.

In my application I have a search textbox with filter button.
When I am adding a text and filter the list as per that I get the result (for filter I am using ng-click=search('F') . 
The result has a edit and delete buttons for each. Now when I open the result data for editing(using edit button) then close it with top right "X" button the ng-click = reset() is called and the filtered values go off.

I want the the filtered values to remain even after i open the files for edit and close it.
As the code is confidential I can just put up the code for "X" button

```
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-ng-click="Reset()">&times;</button>
```

the code for search filter button is:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnFilter" ng-click="Search('F')">
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp; Filter &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    </button>
```

Hope I am clear. Please let me know if any other clarification required. I need help with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you are not clearing the search text box value inside your `Reset()` method ?

Comment: No. Because after I close the form the text remains in the search textbox. I need to click on filter button again to get the filtered value. I don't want to click on filter  button again. even after i open and close the form the filtered values should remain.

Comment: Is it possible to call Search function inside reset function in angular js?

Comment: yes it is possible, but it is not the right approach. How have you implemented your search logic ? is it simple filter in `ng-repeat` like `ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchField"` or some other custom logic where you are re-creating the list ? Also, what is the object structure of your list ?

Comment: Its other custom logic which recreates the list

Comment: Then of course you will have to re-run your search / filter logic after you are done with your edit / delete functionality. had it been a simple ng-repeat filter, angular would have done it for you using 2-way binding and ng-repeat watchers. But, in your case, call your search method from your edit and delete method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using custom search / filter logic and are re-creating the list after filter, then you will have to re-run your search / filter logic after you are done with your edit / delete functionality.

Had it been a simple ng-repeat filter, angular would have done it for you using 2-way binding and ng-repeat watchers.

But, in your case, call your search method at end of your edit and delete method

Comment: You mean angular js reset function i should call search function?

Comment: yes call you search function at the end of you reset function

Comment: Also, mark this as an answer and give an up-vote, if this has solved your issue.